# Show A and B are similar to same diagonal matrix. Then find inv matrix P.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that A and B are similar by showing that they are similar to the same diagonal matrix. Then find an invertible matrix P such that $P^{-1}$AP=B.

A = $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    2&1&0\\ 0&-2&1\\ 0&0&1
    \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ 
B = $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    3&2&-5\\ 1&2&-1\\ 2&2&-4
    \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

I found the $\lambda$ values by taking the det(A - $\lambda$I) and det(B - $\lambda$I) which are $\lambda_1$ = 2, $\lambda_2$ = -2, $\lambda_3$ = 1

This suggests that A and B are similar to the diagonal matrix: 
    $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    2&0&0\\ 0&-2&0\\ 0&0&1
    \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ I think..

Where to go from here? I began taking the det(A - $\lambda_1$I) and ended up with the RREF matrix: $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
        0&1&0\\ 0&0&-1\\ 0&0&0
        \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
It would appear that I have 2 free variables since I have one pivot entry, however, I am unfamiliar with how eigenspaces work. How can I find $E_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: we know there exist invertible $\;Q,R\;$ s.t.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&\!\!-2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=Q^{-1}AQ=R^{-1}BR\implies\left(QR^{-1}\right)^{-1}A\left(QR^{-1}\right)=B$$

Comment: Would you mind breaking your syntax down a little bit. For me, it just makes things more confusing.